# checking if application is active

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I'm writing an application in gtk and xlib
I wanted to check if the application has focus or not(I want to make sure that if I type typing will go to another application not this one)
I'm calling

```
if(gtk_window_is_active(main_window)) {
```

wher the main window has been declared globally
and initialized:

```
main_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
```

and

```
gtk_window_set_keep_above ( (GtkWindow *) main_window, TRUE);
```

I'm calling this when a combobox changes, and it's running but it always returns false(even though I had just changed the combobox, which as far as I understand should make the application active again)
maybe I'm using the wrong function
how can I detect if my application is the active one?

Comment: What version of gtk+?

Comment: 2.x 
I have the application working on hosts with gtk 2.0 up to 3.x